# using zend framework with zend server

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

I am considering to use Zend Framework in a future project in a Linux Environment. I did the introduction tutorial and quite liked the framework. Yet there's one question i couldn't really find an answer around.

What is the benefit of using Zend Server CE , besides that it wraps up MsSQL and PHP and Apache? As far as i figured out , you still need to include or link zend framework in your application. I couldn't find any facilities which will make deployment any easier either.

It would be nice if someone could give some pointers / resources about pros/cons of using Zend Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plan is to set up a live server my tip would be to not use the Zend Server CE. It is quite heavy, I would use apache/mysql and then add your ZF dir to include path in the php.ini

I used Zend Server CE on my Mac earlier, just for development, but i throw it out and now i use MAMP instead.

What I liked about Zend Server CE is the admin interface, read more about it here http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/